# This iPhone 6 is running iOS 12.4.1 (16G102), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Getting the error

> This iPhone 6 is running iOS 12.4.1 (16G102), which may not be
>   supported by this version of Xcode.

while trying to run the app on iPhone after updating the iPhone.

I know that I can update the Xcode and System both and the issue will be resolved but I want to be able to install the apps on iPhone without updating the Xcode and MacOS.

Please help.

Tried nothing yet.

Can not share the code. No code to show here.

Comment: what is _this_ version of Xcode, exactly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Issue:** 
This iPhone 6 is running iOS 12.4.1 (16G102), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

**Resolution:**

**a). If the issue is not replicated on your another device with latest Xcode version**

We need to add the support files in the Xcode. The files can be found on a system with latest Xcode on the path -

1. Go to Applications.
2. Right click on Xcode, click on "Show Package Contents".
3. Go to Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport
4. Copy support files for the iPhone version.

Paste the file into the system in which you are facing the issue in same path as of above. Close the Xcode and run the code again to refresh the files.

**b). If you don't have a system with latest Xcode.**

Download the file "iOS 12.4 Developer Disk Image" from the https://github.com/xushuduo/Xcode-iOS-Developer-Disk-Image/releases and unzip the file. Rename the folder to "12.4.1 (16G102)" and paste the file into the system in which you are facing the issue in below path:

1. Go to Applications.
2. Right click on Xcode, click on "Show Package Contents".
3. Go to Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platforms -> DeviceSupport

Close the Xcode and run the code again to refresh the files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I am able to run the app on iPhone :)

Answer (score 4):

[You need to add device support files from this link](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

Follow these steps to add device support files

1. Go into Application and right click on Xcode.app then click on show package contents
2. Go into this path Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceS‌​upport/
3. Get device support file 12.4 from attached link. Unzip it and rename to 12.4.1(16G102) and paste renamed file to above path under device support.
4. Restart Xcode and then run application on device.

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I tried several things but the only solution is to update your Xcode to **11.3.1**. After the update I tried to run on my iPhone and worked perfectly!

[image: iphone not supported on xcode]