# Is there a workaround for Xcode 12.4 to work on Ios 15?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Mac 10.15 with Xcode 12.4 and my IOS is 15. I dont want to update my catalina os at all. Could i just download the IOS 15 folder and install it to my xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update your Mac with Catalina OS. You simply add device support files for iOS 15 into Xcode.

[download device support file from this link](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

Comment: if you don't know how to add device support files then have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075799/8259188