# How to build for newer iOS versions with outdated Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, macos

I have MacBook Air 2012 on MacOs Mojave with the latest version of MacOs I can install being Catalina. The latest version of Xcode that Catalina supports is Xcode 12.4, which only can build for iOS 14.4 and older. But my iPhone has iOS 14.7 and I can't downgrade it.  Is it possible to build for iOS 14.7 with Xcode 12.4 or, better, Xcode 11.3 since I use Mojave?
Using simulator is not an option because I need to access bluetooth.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can I install an older iOS with jailbreak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use iOS 14.7 on Xcode 12.4. You only need to add device support file in Xcode for iOS 14.7.

[You need to add device support file from this link](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

Comment: Also Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075799/8259188 if you don't know how to add device support files.